# How to conditionally delete values in excel?

Tags: ms-office

I need to enter the values of Twelve thousand (12,000) books of a library and need to verify the stock of it. The books don't have any barcodes but have only serial numbers from 1 to 12,000 not in a particular order throughout the library. I decided to use excel to verify the book numbers.

Now my doubt is, is there any way in excel that if you enter a value (in my case 1 to 12,000) in a fixed cell (say A2 or B2...) the entered value gets deleted from that respective cell where it was sitting?

To put my question in another way, can i keep entering values into a cell (i.e the books i have in the library) and keep pressing enter, and the values i entered in that cell keep deleting from a given table one after another so that I can figure out what books in the library are lost from the remaining values in the table?

If this whole Excel method is complicated for the task, anyone please suggest any other alternatives that can make my work easy.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to generate a list of serial numbers that do not exist in the range of 1-12000. If you must type them in one by one, go ahead and do that first and then use a function like match() or countif() to flag the ones that aren't represented in the list you just entered. You will need to create a master list of all items 1-12000 and enter your formula next to that master list.

Comment: After you flag the ones you want, sort the master list and the formula column as one unit to isolate the hits.